# How to record a video in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am using **Xam.Plugin.Media** to take photo and video. The code below is to record the video the problem is the camera is not opening when I click the button. I tried to uninstall and install the Nuget package and deleted the bin and obj still nothing. I also tried different phones with different api still nothing worked. I hope you can help me

```
try
{
   var cafNo = entCafNo.Text;

   await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

   if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakeVideoSupported)
   {
      await DisplayAlert("No Camera", "No Camera Available", "Ok");
      return;
   }

   var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakeVideoAsync(
   new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreVideoOptions
   {
        SaveToAlbum = false,
        Name = cafNo + "_VID.mp4",
        CompressionQuality = 80,
        Quality = VideoQuality.Low
   }
   );

   entVideoUrl.Text = file.Path;

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   Console.Write(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Is the code throwing an exception and going into the catch block? If so, what is the exception?

Comment: @HofmaDresu there is no exception showing the code is executing successfully the problem is the camera is not opening

Comment: Have you debug on iPhoneSimulator? I use the same code as you and it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android security architecture provision: by default, no application has permission to perform any action that adversely affects other applications, operating systems, or users. This includes reading and writing users' private data (such as contacts or emails), reading and writing files from other applications, performing network access, keeping devices awake, performing camera access,and so on.

To use these protected device capabilities, first add one or more < uses-permission > tags in the application manifest file (androidmanifest.xml).

In xamarin.forms,you can refer to the link [here](https://blog.xamarin.com/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow/)